# Kaltura Notifications are occationally deactivated?

Tags: kaltura

We are using Kaltura to notify our CMS about changes in the videos. In the KMC under Settings->Integrations Settings we have checked all the checkboxes under "Sent by Server".
Some times these checkmarks disappear? IT happens maybe once a week or once a month. How can we find the reason to these boxes being deactivated?

Answer (score 0):

Those notifications are being stored on the partner object in `partner` table. The actual data is stored in the `custom_data` field, which holds large amount of PHP-serialized data.
I can suspect cases that due to updates of other fields in the `custom_data` object, the notifications section will be erased.

Your best shot would be first check the value of that field when the config got erased. If it was actually erased in the database, try to find the following log messages in `api_v3.log` (which can lead you to the actual API request that modified the field):

```
[2124167851][propel] */ UPDATE partner SET 
`UPDATED_AT`='2017-10-04 14:11:36', 
`NOTIFY`='1', 
`CUSTOM_DATA`='a:79:{s:9:"firstName";s:5:"Roman";s:12:"isFirstLogin";b:0; 

... tons of PHP serialized data ...  

i:1;s:19:"notificationsConfig";s:42:"*=0;1=1;2=1;3=1;4=0;21=0;6=0;7=0;26=0;5=0;";

... tons of PHP serialized data ...  

}' WHERE partner.ID='101' AND MD5(cast(partner.CUSTOM_DATA as char character set latin1)) = '7eb7781cc04c7f98077efc2e3c1e9426'
```

The key that stores the notifications config is `notificationsConfig` (Each number represents the notification type, then `0` / `1` for `off` / `no`).

As a side note, which CE version are you using? There might be a more reliable way to integrate with your CMS.

Comment: Thanks for your input! This is really interesting. Unfortunately we use the hosted solution at Kaltura so we cannot see the content of this database.